# Strange marks on the Wall?

Tags: lateral-thinking, enigmatic-puzzle

On an adventure looking through an Egyptian pyramid, you find weird marks on the walls. *It seems as though they are different, yet strangely similar from hieroglyphics... Strange...*

Further down into the pyramid you come across **similar markings**. You move on, telling yourself you'll come back to it.

You reach the end of the tunnel, and find **English**. Since when is English in a pyramid? Are you going crazy? *The carved words say:*

> A spin top, a pyramid, language. Basic, yet confusing, what could've happened?

When you finish reading it, **a virtual keyboard and a small screen appear.**

*This is when you realize you've made the biggest Egyptian discovery yet! They were very advanced! Or did they work with aliens?*

Before you have time to think of any other theories, *the door closes behind you, locking you in!*

You have to put something on the keypad. The small screen says

> Where are you?

**Ultimately confused, it's now your job to find your way out of this! Where are you?**

Comment: I can't tell how good the particular puzzle is without solving it, but the sheer rate and which you're posting these makes me suspect you aren't taking the time to think about and revise them, which makes me disinclined to try. You've posted 10 puzzles within the last two days, and 7 of them are negatively voted. I think you have a lot of good ideas but are posting them prematurely. These ideas deserve better. You should take the time to make a few well-polished puzzles rather than many slipshod ones.

Comment: @xnor This is a good one... You can't DV based on the fact that I've messed up the past few times...

Comment: I don't believe xnor is downvoting this question or advocating that others do, simply pointing out that **you have good puzzles, they deserve to be edited and presented coherently**. I often encounter your puzzles and find them unanswerable (and not in a good way) because critical details and definitions are omitted. When I look again the next day, they are generally fixed. I think xnor is advising you to fix them before you post. I am.

Comment: @frodo Sometimes I do not notice it. Writing puzzles is hard.

Comment: Unless there is something pointing me in a special direction, I'd be inclined to answer "Disneyland", but that seems too broad for a proper puzzle... Is there anything which *restricts* valid answers? If so, you should add it before a punch of wild guesses like mine ruin your puzzle! U think, that's what xnor meant as well...

Comment: ...the screen asks "where are you" because you've found an emergency phone...

Comment: @warspyking Pro tip: when people give you honest criticism, don't get defensive. When you argue against criticism, you're discouraging people from giving you feedback in the future. Instead, ask questions if you're confused, decide yourself whether the criticism is useful, and then thank your commenters for trying to help you compose better puzzles.

Comment: @BmyGuest The English is what restricts the answers.

Comment: Important piece of missing information: what keys are on the "keypad"? "Pad" often implies a subset of a full key "board" -- e.g. "number pad".

Comment: @warspyking I think the 'problem' with this *brainteaser* tagged puzzle (for me at least) is, that I don't know the basic direction: Is it some *riddle* cleverly hidden in the text, or is it some *real-life-problem* which requires some creative thinking, or is it as *phantastic* puzzle, allowing all sorts of creative outputs, or is it a *logical* conclusion (albeit creative), I'm after... You see where I'm aiming at? Without having an idea of the *nature* of the puzzle, it's even hard to start. The only exception would be a "You-see-it-you-get-it" puzzle where the solution is *blazingly* clear

Comment: @BmyGuest Isn't it implied you have to figure out where you are given the the information in the puzzle?

Comment: @Josh Fixed, sorry for the conclusion

Comment: Not for me, no. What tells me my Disneyland solution is not correct? If I'd knew it had to be a location derived from the *text* (i.e every 1013th letter...) and I couldn't provide the *rule*, I'd know I'm wrong. But if it is just *brainteaser* it could very well *be* the correct answer. (it is not, is it?)

Comment: @BmyGuest Explain how you got Disneyland from *"A spin top, a pyramid, language. Basic, yet confusing, what could've happened?
"*

Comment: Disneyland has carrousels (spin top), themed buildings (pyramid) theaters (language). The solution is very basic, yet the puzzle was meant to confuse...

Comment: If the two *quoted* texts are **all you need to solve the puzzle**, you should state this, I think.

Comment: But Bmy, the puzzle specifically states your in Egypt, Disneyland isn't in Egypt.

Comment: Also, the answer is not Egypt. It is however somewhere in it.

Comment: @BmyGuest You need the whole puzzle...

Comment: Actually, it only states you're in an Egyptian Pyramid, not that you're in Egypt. The size of the Egyptian empire changed over history, and buildings could have been moved... Or reconstructed...

Comment: @Bmy While true, still not Disneyland.

Comment: Strongly agreed with BmyGuest's last comment. My _immediate_ assumption on reading the first line was that "through an Egyptian pyramid" was a bit of misdirection, that the character was not actually in Egypt.

Comment: @warspyking As frodoskywalker explains well, I'm not downvoting or encouraging others to downvote based on past questions, but encouraging you to edit your puzzles before posting rather than others having to edit them afterwards.

Comment: @Josh Why would you think that?

Comment: Well, first because of a bit of meta-puzzling: it's a good ploy for a puzzle to put you slightly off the scent right from the start. But I probably misemphasized; it wasn't the first sentence alone. The highlighting of the weirdness of the discoveries, _combined with_ the decidedly non-definitive description "Egyptian" -- with no other points in the puzzle apparently supporting the idea that it actually takes place in Egypt or a literally "Egyptian" pyramid -- led me to the conclusion that my initial thought was correct. (Let me know if that's not clear and I'll try to reword.)

Comment: @Josh It honestly don't matter to the puzzle...

Comment: How do readers know that?

Comment: @Josh They wouldn't have if I didn't tell you.. They weren't supposed to...

Comment: So then that's a dead end for solvers. What tells them that it's a dead end?

Comment: @Josh It's a purposeful red herring. Besides, the tag is brainteaser...

Comment: We're just going around in circles now. Is [the entire text necessary](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6352/strange-marks-on-the-wall#comment20738_6352) to solve the puzzle, or is  there misdirection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You find **English** in the tunnel because are in a 1 dollar  bill. The **pyramid** is the one behind it. The **spin top** is the pyramid´s top, separated from the rest, where we can see the eye. And the **language** proves the answer is *one dollar bill*, because the greek word *logos*(λόγος), means written or spoken words, in the case of the bill, written words.

Like it was said, *the answer is not Egypt, but somewhere in it*. I would say that **the one dollar bill is in Egypt**.